# Пара вопросов про фиксированном меню и прокрутке

Tags: jquery, css

У меня есть фиксированное меню и там есть логотип, который имеет белый цвет. При опускании меню вниз фон менюшки должен становиться белым, а лого черным и цвет шрифтов должен меняться. У меня лишь вышло изменить фон меню, как сделать остальное?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll > 250) {
        $(".site-nav").css("background", "white" );

      }

      else{
          $(".site-nav").css("background" , "");

      }
  })
})
```

HTML код менюшки:

```
<header class="site-header">
  <nav class="site-nav">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#!">
        <img src="assets/img/logo.png" width="100" class="main-logo" alt="logo">
      </a>
      <span class="main-nav-trigger">&#9776;</span>
      <ul class="horizontal-nav ">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

css код менюшки:

```
.site-header {
.bg-img('hero-img.jpg');
background-attachment: fixed;
padding-bottom: 450px;

}
.site-nav {
padding: 25px 48px;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
  ul {
    &:extend(.ul-unstyled);
    float: right;

    li {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 15px;
      a {
        .transition();
        display: block;
        color: #bababa;
        line-height: 1.65;
        font-family: "Work Sans";
        font-weight: 500;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        line-height: 1;
        padding: 22px 17px;
        font-size: 18px;

        &:hover {
          color: #ededed;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: $("селектор").css("color", "white" ); $("селектор").css("font", "и тут какой надо выбрать шрифт" );

Comment: @Air  Добавил, но ничего не происходит. А как логотипу цвет сменить? на черный при прокрутке.                                                     $(".site-nav").css("background", "white" ); $(".site-nav").css("color", "black");

Comment: Остин, будь другом, весь код... И HTML и CSS

Comment: @Air добавил в описание еще html и css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное я понял, что именно у тебя происходило...
 Вот твой коммент

> @Air Добавил, но ничего не происходит. А как логотипу цвет сменить? на черный при прокрутке. $(".site-nav").css("background", "white" ); $(".site-nav").css("color", "black"); – Остин 8 часов назад

ты пытался менять

> css("background", "white" ) background

на

> css("color", "black") color

Обрати внимания на комментарии JS

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 250) {
      //  в этой части кода надо прописывать стили те на которые хочешь сменить
      $(".site-nav").css("background", "white");
      $("img").css("background", "black");
      $("a").css("font-family", "Calibri");

    } else {
      // а в этой части кода надо прописывать стили те на которые у тебя в css
      // потому, что когда ты JS-ом меняешь стили, у JS приоритет и у тебя стили 
      // прописываются таким образом прям в HTML см строку ниже
      //<img style="background: red;">
      // раскомментируй строку ниже и увидишь разницу 
      //$("img").css("background", "white");
      $(".site-nav").css("background", "");

      $("a").css("font-family", "Times New Roman");
    }
  })
})
```

```css
*,
* ::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000%;
  background: #272727;
  color: white;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.site-header {
  padding-bottom: 450px;
}

.site-nav {
  padding: 25px 48px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
}

img {
  background: green;
}

ul {
  float: right;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

a {
  display: block;
  color: #bababa;
  line-height: 1.65;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 22px 17px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

a:hover {
  color: #ededed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <header class="site-header">
    <nav class="site-nav">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#!">
          <img src="http://all-unreal.my1.ru/sml/RoLLs/UT-3.gif" width="100" class="main-logo" alt="logo">
        </a>
        <span class="main-nav-trigger">&#9776;</span>
        <ul class="horizontal-nav ">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```